# Java Swing panel layered on top with centered text

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a simple Jeopardy-esque game:

[image]

using Java Swing. It's obviously a JFrame with a JPanel in it and buttons in rows.

Now what I need is to add a layered panel with a centered and wrapped text in it:

[image]

Which I can remove later. I already tried using JTextPane and JTextArea and JPanel, none of those want to even display. The best effect I have achieved with AWT Panel, it does display but I can't center or wrap text in it.

Here's some code for which I appologise, I would usually try to make it short and readable but since it's not working I don't know what to do with it to make ti look better:

```
    JLabel questionLabel = new JLabel(questionList.get(randomNumber).getQuestion(), SwingConstants.CENTER);
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20);

    //------------------JTextPane--------------------

    JTextPane questionPane = new JTextPane();
    questionPane.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    questionPane.setSize(gameWidth, gameHeight);
    questionPane.setText(questionList.get(randomNumber).getQuestion());
    questionPane.setFont(font);
    questionPane.setEditable(false);

    //------------------AWT panel--------------------
    Panel awtPanel = new Panel();
    awtPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    awtPanel.setSize(game.getWidth(),game.getHeight());
    Label labelQuestion = new Label("<html>" + questionList.get(randomNumber).getQuestion() + "</html>", Label.CENTER);
    labelQuestion.setFont(font);
    awtPanel.setForeground(Color.white);

    awtPanel.add(labelQuestion);

    //------------------JPanel-----------------------
    JPanel layeredPanel = new JPanel();
    layeredPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    layeredPanel.setSize(game.getWidth(),game.getHeight());
    JLabel jLabelQuestion = new JLabel("<html>" + questionList.get(randomNumber).getQuestion() + "</html>", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabelQuestion.setFont(font);
    layeredPanel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    layeredPanel.add(jLabelQuestion, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    game.getLayeredPane().add(layeredPanel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    button.setEnabled(false);
    font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16);

    button.add(jLabelQuestion, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    button.setDisabledIcon(new ImageIcon(source.getScaledInstance(gameWidth/4, gameHeight/5, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));

    questionList.remove(randomNumber);

    logger.info(questionList.size());

    game.getLayeredPane().remove(layeredPanel);
```

UPDATE: I chnaged to SWT rather than Swing, and I use the StackLayout with a few Composites in it, and just change between them as I see fit.

Comment: You should not have to resort to using AWT Panel.  Please explain what is wrong with JTextPane, etc. and what your question is.

Comment: Do you want the layerd pannel to appear ontop of the buttons?

Comment: yes, just like "visualised" in the picture. The JTextPane does not display itself. I am fairly new to Swing, as in I started using it yesterday so there might be some kind of initialisation mistake maybe

Answer (score 2):

You can generally solve issues like this with a JLabel.

I would recommend encapsulating the above grid in the BorderLayout.CENTER of another pane, perhaps a new content pane. Then, add the caption to BorderLayout.NORTH.

As a more tangible example,

```
private void createContent() {
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //establish the panel currently set as center, here labeled "everythingElse"
    this.getContentPane().add(everythingElse, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Create a JLabel with your caption
    JLabel jlbl = new JLabel("Question");
    //format that caption, most details being rather obvious, but most importantly:
    jlbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); //keeps text centered
    this.getContentPane().add(jlbl, BorderLayout.NORTH); //add it to the top of the panel

    //...other cleanup operations...
}
```

The issue with grid panes is that they have a limited tolerance for the number of components visible in them. If you overload one, it won't show. For BorderLayout panes, you can easily swap new items into and out of them.

For efficiency's sake, I might recommend compiling this JLabel as a final somewhere else in your code, and holding onto it for when you need it. This way, you will also dodge overhead from repeatedly creating the label object.

Lastly, avoid AWT whenever you can. It's been deprecated for an excess of ten years, and if you do use it you will run into numerous critical problems involving heavyweight and lightweight component incompatibilities. If you intend to use another windowing kit, consider implementing the new standard, JavaFX, with a JFXPane-- it's much more tolerant of HTML syntax, as well.